# How to remove the small blue line in bootstrap buttons?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want to remove the tiny blue line in the left side of the delete button

[image]

This is the code:

```
<ul class="list-group">
            {{range $i, $page := .pages}}
              <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-dark d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                {{$page.Title}}
                <span class="justify-content-end">
                  <a href="/page/{{$page.ID}}/show">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark me-1">
                      Edit
                    </button>
                  </a>
                  <a href="/page/{{$page.ID}}/delete">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                      Delete
                    </button>
                  </a>
                </span>
              </li>
            {{end}}
          </ul>
```

Any advice how can i do that ?

Comment: The problem doesn’t show up with the code snippet that you provided (with the fields for your server removed). Can you provide enough of your code from your page as viewed in the browser so the problem can be replicated?

Comment: This is likely the underline formatting that links get by default. But putting `button` into `a` is not allowed in HTML to begin with, so you should fix the broken HTML first of all here.

Comment: i solved it using: a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

Comment: @BlackGopher see my last part of answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see is `text-decoration` "the problem"

Without:

```css
a:hover{
   text-decoration: none!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ul class="list-group">
            
              <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-dark d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <span class="justify-content-end">
                  <a href="/page/{{$page.ID}}/show">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark me-1">
                      Edit
                    </button>
                  </a>
                  <a href="/page/{{$page.ID}}/delete">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                      Delete
                    </button>
                  </a>
                </span>
              </li>
          </ul>
```

With:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ul class="list-group">
            
              <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-dark d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <span class="justify-content-end">
                  <a href="/page/{{$page.ID}}/show">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark me-1">
                      Edit
                    </button>
                  </a>
                  <a href="/page/{{$page.ID}}/delete">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                      Delete
                    </button>
                  </a>
                </span>
              </li>
          </ul>
```

As @CBroe wrote into comment, is always well adjust the code with valid html

Correct version:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ul class="list-group">
            
              <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-dark d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <span class="justify-content-end">
                  <a href="/page/{{$page.ID}}/show" type="button" class="btn btn-dark me-1">
                      Edit
                  </a>
                  <a href="/page/{{$page.ID}}/delete" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                      Delete
                  </a>
                </span>
              </li>
          </ul>
```

As you can see i change `<a>` with type `button` so now you have same result without underline or manual css change.

Comment: The last part of your comment. yea i tried it and it worked, its actually better but is that nice to do, i mean normal ?

Comment: the last part is the best way to use good html and come to desired result

Comment: Please flag it as answer for help all community with same problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

I think the tiny blue line is the underline of delete word.